# a que se debe "Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host." en Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

modifique una parte del MainActivity.Java y ahora me sale un error **Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host.** y en el emulador de android studio me marca **System UI isn't responding**, por otrol lado en el archivo de **activity_main.xml** me aparece un error **Desing editor is unavalible until a successful project sync** podrían decirme a que se debe esto y como lo soluciono.

Comment: Ya pudiste resolverlo?, pues ami me aparece lo mismo y no he podido resolverlo

Comment: hola que tal sinceramente no eh encontrado solución para ese problema sospecho que en mi caso es  por el equipo ya que cuenta con pocos recursos a nivel de hardware, por lo que he estado trabajando mi proyecto en mi equipo personal que cuenta con mas recursos y ahi no he tenido ningún problema relacionado, modifico mis archivos, las paqueterías y no eh tenido ese problema, te recomiendo si tienes la posibilidad intenta utilizar otro equipo, la computadora en la que trabajaba y me salía el error es AMD y el mi equipo personal cuento con procesador i7 de séptima

Comment: Yo tratando de resolver desisntale las platform-tools y volvi a instalar y  funciono un tiempo o al menos pense que fue por eso. pero ya de repente empezo  a funcionar y al dia siguiente no ,  y despues si,  pero ahora ya me esta fallando    y no se por que es , no he podido  resolverlo estoy pensando en reinstalar android studio, pues mi lap si tiene core i7  y me sigue pasando